# PHPStorm index new file

Tags: phpstorm

How do you see what files are indexed in your project when using PHPStorm. Are all files that are listed under the project necessarily indexed?

I will have cases where files will be overwritten (or added to the project) from outside the IDE and I want to be sure that these files will still be indexed. For example, I do not want to overwrite a file in windows explorer and then not have the changes be picked up in PHPStorm when doing a search or refactoring operation.

Similarly, I want to add files to the project by dragging and dropping them in the Project Tool Window on the left.

Comment: *"For example, I do not want to overwrite a file in windows explorer and then not have the changes be picked up in PHPStorm when doing a search or refactoring operation."* IDE re-checks your project files each time you bringing it to focus (unless you have disabled such behaviour). You can always force rescan by using `File | Synchronize`

Comment: *"Similarly, I want to add files to the project by dragging and dropping them in the Project Tool Window on the left."* It does not work like that. If file is inside the project folder, then it's already part of the project (unless folder is already marked as Excluded). You cannot reference random file from outside the project -- only whole folder, which can then be added as Additional Content Root -- https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/configuring-content-roots.html?search=content

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne, I thought the synchronize had to do with submitting the file to the web server. So Synchronize re indexes a file in your project?  Also, you mentioned when coming into focus, was this w.r.t. the IDE itself or the file in question, i.e. do I need to open a file copied in externally in the IDE to ensure it is scanned, or simply give focus to the IDE (click on it / maximize it)

Comment: When dragging a file from windows explorer and dropping it on the project tool window on the folder where you want it, the file is moved to that directory. When doing this though I got the same PHPStorm notice that you get when you edit a file from a location not in your project, which left me concerned that even though the file lies in the project's physical directory and it is displayed in the project, that it is not actually part of the project

Comment: IDE should index new/modified files just fine when it's gaining focus. If not -- force it manually (it will do that for the whole project). Yes, auto-detection may not work well if file is on network/slow disk access; sometimes it may also happen with symlinked files (at least it was the case in the past, like 2 years ago). It seems to be working fine here on Windows 7 -- I do not remember the need of re-opening the file to see the changes, especially in latest current version.

Comment: Not sure about your last comment -- I need to see some screenhots (or much better -- screencast) to understand the issue here. As far as I'm aware -- if you drag a file into IDE from outside it just opens it from THAT location -- it does not add it to the project. For example -- you cannot move (Cut & Paste on Windows) files from outside into project folder -- only copy (Copy & Paste).

Comment: Thanks for the responses @LazyOne. I confirmed that Synchronizing does reindex a file and that the IDE does this periodically as well. W.r.t. the moving of files, maybe they changed the behavior in PHPStorm 9, but when I drop a file from explorer onto a folder in the project view, it moves the file there.

Answer (score 0):

Try toUse git or any other VCS system. It is incredibly useful for such more routines along yours.

Comment: I agree, in this case though there will be files that need to be added externally, so I need to know if this needs to be done in a specific way